# Laravel One to Many Relation query binding shows null?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have following tables. Laravel convention is not followed. 
Tables

```
 helpdesk_logs (table)
 id primary_key

 helpdesk_files (table)
 id primary_key
 helpdesk_logs_id - foreign_key
```

Model

HelpdeskLogs.php

```
    public function helpdeskFiles(){

        return $this->hasMany( 'Defsys\Modules\helpdesk\Models\HelpdeskFiles','helpdesk_logs_id','id');
    }
```

HelpdeskFiles.php

```
public function helpdeskLogs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( 'Defsys\Modules\helpdesk\Models\HelpdeskLogs','helpdesk_logs_id' );
}
```

I am performing following task

```
HelpdeskLogs::with('helpdeskFiles')
              ->select( DB::raw( 'helpdesk_logs.id AS helpdesk_logs_id,helpdesk_logs.description,helpdesk_logs.status ,helpdesk_logs.spent_time' ) )
           ->where( 'helpdesk_logs.id', 13)->get();
```

Despite records are there in helpdesk_files(for helpdesk_lod_id 13) It does not return any record. binding params shows null

when i debug query it shows following

```
1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `helpdesk_files` where `helpdesk_files`.`helpdesk_logs_id` in (?)"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => null
    ]
    "time" => 0.17
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your helpdesk logs table id colunn can be used to retrieve required results
`HelpdeskLogs::with('helpdeskFiles')->where( 'id', 13)->get();`

Comment: sorry that was typo actually(while copying) I have other column helpdesk_id also. I have records with helpdesk_log_id 13 in helpdesk_files table

Comment: @kamlesh.bar can you post the correct code in your question. I'm not able to understand the issue.. :(

Comment: thanks @jaysingkar issue resolved. the problem was with 'select 'statement it doesn't have id (helpdesk_logs.id) i have added along with helpdesk_logs.id AS helpdesk_logs_id